# Extensibility (plugins) in a UWP app

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

We are investigating whether UWP can be a suitable replacement for our WPF apps. In our WPF apps, we use extensibility (plugins) to add additional (customer specific) logic to our apps. We currently use NuGet packages to deploy / update these extensions and load them at runtime.

In UWP, is it possible to:

1. Dynamically load plugins in UWP (I think this is not possible because the sandbox will probably prevent loading dynamic modules)?
2. Deliver these extensions via the store (but they need to be hidden for any other users)?

Comment: Try use LoadPackagedLibrary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the Anniversary Update UWP natively supports app extensions that can be distributed through Windows Store. You can find more info [here](https://mtaulty.com/2016/08/03/windows-10-anniversary-update-app-extensions-and-app-services/), [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38b040ba-f445-421d-8db0-946b31a5a156/uwp-application-plugins?forum=wpdevelop) or [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/windows-10-anniversary-sdk-is-bringing-exciting-opportunities-to-developers/#6fWQDH6gHMc5y2uv.97).

You can manage the visibility of your UWP apps (and I think it will work the same with app extensions) in the Dev Center Dashboard. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability) to get more info.

Answer (score 1):

LoadPackagedLibrary can dynamically load plugins in UWP .

But it only can load the dll in appx.

How to using LoadPackagedLibrary ,see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx

If you want to use the win32 dll that in other directory,please get the LoadLibrary that can use it.

You can use

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info = {};  
if (VirtualQuery(VirtualQuery, &info, sizeof(info)))  
{
    auto kernelAddr = (HMODULE)info.AllocationBase;
    auto loadlibraryPtr = GetProcAddress(kernelAddr, "LoadLibraryExW");
    // load your library here ...
}
```

to get the loadlibrary and use to loadlibrary the dll.

See https://hjc.im/3-ways-to-bypass-wack/

Ms use the PE and P/Invoke to  judge whether uwp use the not allowed dll.

So you can use the loadlibrary to load it.

Comment: It is possible to bypass the WACK but that will lead to undefined behavior if you start calling unsupported APIs, and sooner or later your app will start failing.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT It can pass the wack and call the win32 api and it also can work.

Comment: It might work today but it might break tomorrow. What you're suggesting is unsupported. Nobody should do it in a production app.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT But there is a way to solve it.Ms break the rules in their edge and store app .

Comment: But it is UWP.So it should abide by the rules.